# Nestjs CRON does not work for me when running a project on PM2

Tags: javascript, nestjs, pm2

The key problem is that when I start the nest.js project via PM2, my specific project starts, but CRON does not work for me in time.
And if I launch the project directly, it will work and CRON will also perform its function. The code itself is fine.

```
@Cron('10 15 * * *')
```

I tried different launches of PM2, I’m sure I haven’t tried everything yet and I haven’t found a solution to this problem.